# Restricting grep's --color option to the interactive shell

Tags: grep, zsh, environment-variables

I have the following variable I want to set to make grep behave a certain way:

```
GREP_OPTIONS=--color=always
```

The problem is, I only want this environment variable to be set on the command line. I don't want this variable to be set when I run shell scripts. I have to export it (using 'export GREP_OPTIONS' in zsh) in order for grep to see it. However, that means that shell scripts will also 'inherit' this variable, which I don't want.

How do I handle this situation? Using an alias has the same problem (the shell script executes the alias).

Comment: No, shell scripts don't execute the alias (unless they are zsh scripts and you define the alias in ~/.zshenv (which you shouldn't)).

Comment: I don't know how to do that in `zsh` but in `bash` you can test for the shell state (`i` in `$-`). Thus you could set `GREP_OPTIONS` depending on the result of this test.

Comment: @HaukeLaging zsh also sets `$-`, you can do it in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the answer, actually. Don't use the `GREP_OPTIONS` environment variable, use an alias for grep instead:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

Aliases are normally defined in `~/.zshrc`, which is not read when zsh executes a script.

Comment: Won't simply having `GREP_OPTIONS=--color=always` in .zshrc have exactly the same effect?

Comment: @terdon It depends. The zsh will not read `~/.zshrc` when executing a script. But if the script is run from an interactive shell (which will read `~/.zshrc), it will inherit this shell's environment including `GREP_OPTIONS`.

Comment: @terdon No. If `GREP_OPTIONS` is to have any effect, it has to be in the environment (an unexported shell variable has no effect), and then it will take effect whether invoked from the interactive shell or by a script.