# Variable Scope in ZSH: How to access global variables from within function?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, variable, oh-my-zsh

I have an ever-expanding `.zshrc` file that was getting out of hand so I decided to try to fix it  by breaking it into modular files and sourcing each of them. This works for the most part, but I seem to have some scoping issues related to variables.

Each module file contains a function matching corresponding with the name of the file. For instance: `nvm..zshrc` contains the function (called by the main `.zshrc` file) named `zshrc_config_load_nvm {}`.

Below is a simplified form of the setup I'm using.

### The main .zshrc file

Note that I've thoroughly tested this file and everything in it works just fine.

```bsh
# Load all config files 
# This method basically copied directly from the .oh-my-zsh.sh file.
for config_file ($ZSH_CUSTOM/*.zshrc(N)); do

    # Skip self-inclusion
    if [[ $config_file==".zshrc" || $config_file==".zshenv" ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    
    # The (D) modifier will escape the path so it can be passed to `basename`
    # without quotes. the second param in `basename` removes the file extension.
    local handle=$(basename ${(D)config_file} .zshrc)

    # If the file contains the expected callback function name ...
    # The :t filter will remove the path and file extension.
    if [[ $(command -v "zshrc_config_load_${handle}") ]]; then
        
        # ... Add it to the list of functions to call.
        ZSH_CONFIG_HANDLES+=($handle)
    fi
    # Each config file will call the register function above.
    source $config_file
done

for handle ($ZSH_CONFIG_HANDLES); do

    func="zshrc_config_load_${handle}"

    # Call the function
    $func
done
unset config_file handle func
```

### nvm.zshrc

```bsh
# This line is copied directly from the documentation. 
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"



# The callback function
function zshrc_config_load_nvm {
    
    # Unable to access the $NVM_DIR variable in this scope. 
    source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh --fast-reuse
    # Error: /nvm.sh does not exist.
}
```

#### The Question

**How do I make `export`ed global variables accessible from within the scope of another function, but without passing those values in as arguments?**

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111227/78266) by [Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles-so-stop-being-evil)...

> `export` [in] zsh is shorthand for `typeset -gx`, where the attribute `g` means “global” (as opposed to local to a function) and the attribute `x` means “exported” (i.e. in the environment).

... Therefore I assume that the `$NVM_DIR` variable should be available from within another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions will see the variable that you have set earlier (and exported or not) provided they haven't been set in a subshell or not declared local to some function that has since returned.

Your problem comes from unrelated mistakes in your code:

> ```
> for config_file ($ZSH_CUSTOM/*.zshrc(N)); do
>
>     # Skip self-inclusion
>     if [[ $config_file==".zshrc" || $config_file==".zshenv" ]]; then
>         continue
>     fi
> ```

`[[ somestring ]]` returns true if `somestring` is not the empty string. `$config_file==".zshrc"` is obviously not the empty string, so that test will return true regardless of the value of `$config_file`. So your loop won't do anything.

You probably meant something like `[[ $config_file = .zsh(rc|env) ]]`, though that's a bit pointless given that `$config_file` will never be either `.zshrc` nor `.zshenv` as those are hidden files, so not included by default in glob expansions and anyway `$config_file` also starts with `/path/to/zsh_custome/` (and `.zshenv` doesn't end in `.zshrc`).

`if [[ $config_file -ef $0 ]] continue` to check that `$config_file` is not the script currently being sourced may make more sense.

Other notes:

> ```
>  export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
> ```

Would better be written as:

```
if (( $+XDG_CONFIG_HOME )); then
  export NVM_DIR=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvm
else
  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
fi
```

In:

> ```
>   local handle=$(basename ${(D)config_file} .zshrc)
> ```

The `D` parameter expansion flag (which turns `/home/you/file` to `~/file` for instance) doesn't make sense.

Sounds like you want `local handle=$config_file:t:r` (*root* of *tail* of the file).

> ```
>   if [[ $(command -v "zshrc_config_load_${handle}") ]];
> ```

Is better written as:

```
if command -v "zshrc_config_load_${handle}" >& /dev/null;
```

Which avoids the fork. Or possibly `if (( $+functions[zshrc_config_load_${handle}] ));`.

Instead of doing `var=...` ... `unset var`, you can use `local` in a function or anonymous function:

```
function {
  local var
  ...
}
```

If there was a `$var` from an outer scope (or coming from the environment), that would then leave it alone instead of ending up unsetting it.

Comment: After implementing these changes, I'm still not finding success. But this has helped me realize I have a lot more areas to explore for potential problems – and a lot to learn on this subject. You've pointed out issues that didn't come up in hundreds of searches. So, I have to thank you for that.

Comment: Thanks for this reply! Taught me a bunch.  Really appreciate the thorough line by line explanation of shortcomings and possible improvement.  I've also been doing things like `if [[ $(command ... ` all the time, and didn't realize how much cleaner a simple `if command -v` is.  Similarly I've been doing `[[ ! -z $VAR ]]` instead of `(( $+VAR ))`.  Appreciate it!